# Include Autoware Auto msgs

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am implementing a new vehicle interface for Autoware my simulator, running on a different node, will receive autoware msgs ( VehicleControlCommand or  HighLevelControlCommand). How can I include autoware_auto_msgs in my project?

Thanks, Simon

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376328/include-autoware-auto-msgs/) by [SimoneBenatti](https://answers.ros.org/users/71643/simonebenatti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`autoware_auto_msgs` (the 1.0.0 version, anyway) has been released to the ROS build farm. To use them in a project outside of Autoware.Auto, simply add `<depend>autoware_auto_msgs</depend>` to your `package.xml` file. If you are not using `ament_cmake_auto` (which I highly recommend) then you also need to add `find_package(autoware_auto_msgs REQUIRED)` to your `CMakeLists.txt` file.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2021-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam123](https://answers.ros.org/users/96030/sam123/) on 2022-02-11**:
hi ,@Josh Whitley
i am also facing the same issue.i have done above changes still not resolved.

thanks in advance